# Solving second order differential equations when it equals a number

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation $$ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 2\frac{dy}{dt}+2y = 9.8 $$

So I set up the auxiliary  equation $\lambda^2 + 2\lambda + 2=0$ This then gives the general solution of $$y_c =e^{-t}(A\cos t + B\sin t) $$ This is as far as I've got as don't know how to account for the differential equation = $9.8$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $y_p = a$, substitute and solve.

Comment: so @Moo we are just making a trail solution of a constant as the whole equation equals a constant?

Comment: That is correct. So, you get $2 a = 9.8$, solve for $a$.

Comment: Sorry, I had misssed a 2 there, you are right so far.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Seems obvious now

Comment: What is nice about DEQs is that you can very your answers rather easily.

Comment: If the right hand side is a constant, then try a constant solution

Answer (score 2):

Your given equation is

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 2\frac{dy}{dt}+2y = 9.8$

$\implies (D^2+2D+2)y=9.8$

where $D \equiv \frac{d}{dt}$

I think you have an idea about how to find the Complementary Function (i.e., C.F.), (for your case, which is nothing but the solution of the homogeneous differential equation $y''+2y'+2=0$).

Here C.F. is $e^{-t}(A\cos t + B\sin t)$.

Now for the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.)

P.I. $=\frac{1}{D^2+2D+2} 9.8 =\frac{1}{2(1+D+\frac{D^2}{2})} 9.8= \frac{1}{2}(1+D+\frac{D^2}{2})^{-1} 9.8 = \frac{1}{2} (1-D-\frac{D^2}{2}- . . . ) 9.8 = \frac{9.8}{2}=4.9$

Hence the general solution is

$y=$ C.F. $+$ P.I.

$ = e^{-t}(A\cos t + B\sin t)+4.9$

where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants.